# How to automatically export data form one SQL server to a Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a question intended to get orientation for the following need:

I want to receive data from a remote database in my mysql server.  Let's see: each time a row is inserted on a remote server (not controlled by me,  controlled by a customer of me)  I need a copy of that transaction inserted in my own server.  That way I can give my customer,  reports on some issues regarding to his business.
The easy way is to generate a comma separated file and upload in my server,  but the client want less work on his side,  he wants something automatically done.  However he has some concerns about security and confidentiality.

What tools,  apis,  technologies,  functions, can be used to achieve that,  better opensource,  and better if we can implement ourselves.  Should I open a "door" to his transactional?

Thanks,  Jorge.

Comment: You need to write a convertor tool.... or see if there is 1 out there.  Most DB have convertors to other Types in a general sense, but i would just create a tool to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read about this about 6 months ago, you can't setup real replication between MSSQL and MySQL.

It's possible to setup an ODBC connection from the MSSQL machine to MySQL and run triggers that will update the remote machine.

You might have some troubles with this (what happens if MySQL or the network goes down?).

I would suggest using MSSQL triggers to write a single audit log that you could then consume from the MySQL server when it was running (hopefully continuously).